# Is there a better way to avoid memory leaks when using multiprocessing and request combined?

Tags: python, web-scraping, memory-leaks, request, python-multiprocessing

I'm currently webscraping a single target with the request module and multiprocessing.

I'm using Pool and multiprocessing async.

Each process sends a series of continuous request, in each request I switch randomly the header(User-agent) and the proxy.

After a while I noticed that the pc slowed down and all the request were failing on all scripts.

After some digging I've realized that the issues were not the proxies but the memory leak from the requests.

I've read the other articles about memory leaks with multiprocessing.

My question is, is there any better way to avoid this rather then using the: if __ name __  ==  '__ main __': ?

(Perhaps dumping memory every tot iterations or something similar?)

Here below is my code:

```
a = [[('ab.txt', 'ab', 'abo', 1), ('ac.txt', 'ac', 'aco', 3), ('acz.txt', 'acz', 'ac o', 5), ('ad.txt', 'ad', 'ado', 2), ('ae.txt', 'ae', 'aeo', 4)],[('ab.txt', 'ab', 'abo', 1), ('ac.txt', 'ac', 'aco', 3), ('acz.txt', 'acz', 'ac o', 5), ('ad.txt', 'ad', 'ado', 2), ('ae.txt', 'ae', 'aeo', 4)],[('ab.txt', 'ab', 'abo', 1), ('ac.txt', 'ac', 'aco', 3), ('acz.txt', 'acz', 'ac o', 5), ('ad.txt', 'ad', 'ado', 2), ('ae.txt', 'ae', 'aeo', 4)],[('ab.txt', 'ab', 'abo', 1), ('ac.txt', 'ac', 'aco', 3), ('acz.txt', 'acz', 'ac o', 5), ('ad.txt', 'ad', 'ado', 2), ('ae.txt', 'ae', 'aeo', 4)]]

def hydra_gecko(file_name, initial_letter, final_letter, process_number):
    # url and proxy details here
    response = requests.get(url, headers=header_switcher(), proxies={'http': proxy, 'https': proxy}, timeout=(1, 3))
    # parse html and gather data


for multi_arguments in a:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p:
        print(p.starmap_async(hydra_gecko, multi_arguments))
        p.close()
        p.join()
```

Is there a better way to do this? 
Is there a code to dump memory every tot iteration or something similar better then the above code?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new pool for every `multi_arguments`. That is a waste of resources. If there are more worker processes in total than your CPU has cores, the workers will be fighting over CPU resources and maybe memory, slowing the whole process down.

The whole *purpose* of a pool is handling more items than there are worker functions.

Try this instead (using a single pool):

```
a = [
  ('ab.txt', 'ab', 'abo', 1), ('ac.txt', 'ac', 'aco', 3),
  ('acz.txt', 'acz', 'ac o', 5), ('ad.txt', 'ad', 'ado', 2),
  ('ae.txt', 'ae', 'aeo', 4), ('ab.txt', 'ab', 'abo', 1),
  ('ac.txt', 'ac', 'aco', 3), ('acz.txt', 'acz', 'ac o', 5),
  ('ad.txt', 'ad', 'ado', 2), ('ae.txt', 'ae', 'aeo',4)
  ('ab.txt', 'ab', 'abo', 1), ('ac.txt', 'ac', 'aco', 3),
  ('acz.txt', 'acz', 'ac o', 5), ('ad.txt', 'ad', 'ado', 2),
  ('ae.txt', 'ae', 'aeo', 4), ('ab.txt', 'ab', 'abo', 1),
  ('ac.txt', 'ac', 'aco', 3), ('acz.txt', 'acz', 'ac o', 5),
  ('ad.txt', 'ad', 'ado', 2), ('ae.txt', 'ae', 'aeo', 4)
]

def hydra_gecko(item):
    file_name, initial_letter, final_letter, process_number = item
    # url and proxy details here
    response = requests.get(
      url, headers=header_switcher(),
      proxies={'http': proxy, 'https': proxy},
      timeout=(1, 3)
    )
    # parse html and gather data, return result.
    return response.status_code

if __name__ == '__main__':
# Do **not** choose a number of workers. The default usually works fine.
# If you are worried about memory leaks, set maxtasksperchild
# to refresh the worker process after a certain number of tasks.
with Pool(maxtasksperchild=4) as p:
    for result in p.imap_unordered(hydra_gecko, a):
        print(result)
```